# Adjusting the step of a UI element

Tags: customization

How can I adjust the "step" of a UI element, when clicking the arrows to the left or right?

Currently it moves in 1cm steps and I'd like it to be 1mm.

[image: A UI Element]

Comment: Are you asking how to do this on UI elements you made with python? Or just in the interface in general?

Comment: Just the interface in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The step sizes for properties are programmed in and not easily user adjustable.

While clicking the arrows will always step in the same amount there are a couple of keys that can help if you drag the value instead of clicking each arrow. Holding <kbd>shift</kbd> while dragging will step in smaller sizes, <kbd>Alt</kbd> smaller again (generally half of shift steps) and together even slower.

These adjustments are dynamic, so you can start dragging the value to get close, then hold <kbd>shift</kbd> to slow it down to get the final value.

Comment: Not for me, dragging a value and then holding shift snaps the value back to where it would be if I had been holding shift the whole time ([gif](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/79842)). I wish it worked that way though..